# Error: API rate limit exceeded while running create-hono command with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, hono

npm create hono@latest
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: create-hono@0.5.0

create-hono version 0.5.0
C:\Users\dheer\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:26165
throw new Error(contents.message);
^

Error: API rate limit exceeded for 115.244.41.200. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)
at viaContentsApi (C:\Users\dheer\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:26165:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async main (C:\Users\dheer\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\6bbb1d6f54609fb5\node_modules\create-hono\bin:26309:24)

Node.js v18.18.0
npm notice
npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.8.1 -> 10.5.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dheer\desktop\projects\medium-blog
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-hono

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dheer\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-05T17_26_24_340Z-debug-0.log

I tried to run the above command but it's not working

Comment: [Post a question, not a clipboard](/help/how-to-ask).